# Scaling the Apache Flink In Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

I have my `Flink` streaming job up and running in local Kubernetes. The job reads from a `Kafka` topic, does some (stateless) computation it and writes back to another Kafka topic. The job's checkpoints are saved in S3.
The Flink's command-line tool deploys the job in single pod (replicas), so how do I increase the replicas to increase the operation on data in parallel & throughput of the job?

Comment: Are you using a Flink k8s operator?

Comment: No I use the `flink run` command to deploy the job to the k8s cluster, no operator was installed in the k8s

Comment: And have you deployed it in Application or Session mode? https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/kubernetes/#deployment-modes

Comment: I use the `Application Mode` to isolate them and have their life cycle do not depend on a central cluster

Answer (score 0):

You have (at least) two options:

1. Manually stop the job triggering a savepoint (access the flink cluster in k8s in any way as described in [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/kubernetes/#accessing-flink-in-kubernetes)) and issue a stop with savepoint [command](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/cli/#stopping-a-job-gracefully-creating-a-final-savepoint)), and then recreate the [application cluster k8s resources](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/kubernetes/#application-cluster-resource-definitions) with an updated jobmanager `parallelism` count (so the job is launched with the new parallelism), taskmanager `replicas` count (so there are enough Task Managers/slots for the job parallelism) and adding the `--fromSavepoint` option in the jobmanager `args` pointing to the created savepoint.
2. Use reactive mode (still in [MVP](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/elastic_scaling/#reactive-mode)). See [documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/kubernetes/#using-standalone-kubernetes-with-reactive-mode). Once configured to be in reactive mode (`scheduler-mode: reactive`, see example config in docs: `flink-reactive-mode-configuration-configmap.yaml`) you only need to change the `replica` count in the `flink-taskmanager` k8s deployment (`taskmanager-job-deployment.yaml` file in [docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/kubernetes/#application-cluster-resource-definitions)) and the scheduler will automatically create a savepoint, rescale the app/cluster and restart from the checkpoint.